# C word count program fails when testing for whitespace

Tags: c

I created a simple word counting program ("word": sequence of characters that does not contain whitespace character). My idea is to count a word whenever the program gets a character `ch` such that `ch` is not a whitespace character, but the character preceding `ch`, call it `pre_ch` is a whitespace character.

The following program doesn't quite work (`nw` remains stuck at `0`):

```
/* Program to count the number of words in a text stream */

#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int ch;                       /* The current character */
  int pre_ch = ' ';             /* The previous character */
  int nw = 0;                   /* Number of words */

  printf("Enter some text.\n");
  printf("Press ctrl-D when done > ");
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if ((ch != (' ' || '\t' || '\n')) && 
        (pre_ch == (' ' || '\t' || '\n')))
    {
      ++nw;
    }

    pre_ch = ch;
  }

  printf("\nThere are %d words in the text stream.\n", nw);
}
```

But, if I change the `if` clause to:

```
if ((ch != (' ' || '\t' || '\n')) && 
    (pre_ch == (' ')
```

(remove the tab and newline options for `pre_ch`), the program works. I have no idea why.

Comment: This one has dozens of duplicates, but they are too hard to find. `||` does not work like a list, it works like a separator for a list of conditions. `ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\n'` and so on.

Comment: `if (!isspace(ch)  && isspace(pre_ch))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it looks natural, the compiler does not understand your intent when you write:

```
   if ((ch != (' ' || '\t' || '\n')) && 
        (pre_ch == (' ' || '\t' || '\n')))
```

Instead you need to write:

```
if ((ch != ' ' || ch != '\t'|| ch != '\n') &&
(pre_ch == ' ' || pre_ch == '\t' || pre_ch == ’\n'))
```

That said, you might want to have a peek at `isspace()`in ctype.h